# Delete image onclick in javascript - Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have following js code

```
var page = '<div class="row delete_contact">
              <div class="col-xs-6 contact_item>
                <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="id">ID:</label>
                <div class="controls col-xs-3">
                 <input class="form-control id" name="id" value="' + id +'">
                </div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete_contact_details control-label">
                   <span class="delete_contact_details control-label col-xs-1 glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
                   </span>
                </a>
             </div>
            </div>';
```

when we click on 'delete' image, it has to delete the full row(div). I tried following while page loading

```
$(function() {
   $('.delete_contact_details').on( "click", function() {
       $(this).closest('.delete_contact').remove();
   });
});
```

But it is not calling the below code. Anyone please help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: how? It is completely different. My question is the function I was writing on the page load and it is not calling.

Comment: How you are using `page` variable?

Comment: Because from the script you have provided the `delete_contact` elements are created dynamically

Comment: So the question is exactly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

Its seems you are dynamically generating elements, use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

```
$(function() {
   $(document).on( "click", '.delete_contact_details', function() {
       $(this).closest('.delete_contact').remove();
   });
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.delete_contact_details').click(function() {
       $(this).closest('.delete_contact').remove();
   });
});
```

Comment: `$(function() { });` is another way of writing `$(document).ready(function() {});` So, its basically is same as OP's code